# In france, when are supermarkets closed or close early for the christmas / new years period (2019/2020)?

Tags: france, shopping, public-holidays, opening-hours

Supermarkets e.g. Carrefour, Lidl, Auchan, Intermarche, Super U

All these supermarkets are closed on

1. Wednessday 25 December 2019
2. Wednessday 1 January 2020

Will these supermarkets close early or stay open longer on

1. Tuesday 24 December 2019
2. Thursday 26 December 2019
3. Tuesday 31 December 2019

Any other days between Saturday 21 December 2019 and 1 January 2020 when supermarkets will be closed / close early?

Comment: Do you have a source saying that these supermarkets will be closed on December 25 and January 1st? In recent years, it is more common that supermarkets are open in the morning on Sundays and national holidays. I cannot guarantee for Christmas and New Year's Day, but the supermarkets near my place were open on Bastille Day (July 14)

Answer (score 3):

This may be quite dependent on the region and the location. Stores in northeastern France for instance used to be more restrictive on trading hours, not sure if that is still the case. The larger the city, and the more central the location, the better the chances for extended hours.

I would expect:

- most to have regular hours on the 24th (or maybe close a little bit early),
- fully normal on the 26th for sure (no Boxing Day in France),
- and mostly regular hours on the 31st.

Many will be open on Sundays in December and some may have extended hours on a few days. Of course, it’s always best to check a few days in advance, they usually update their trading hours on their websites for peculiar dates like these (though not as far in advance).

Answer (score 2):

Stores tends to close earlier than usual on 31st : 
Examples :

- Auchan la défense (Paris(ish)) close at 6 PM instead of 9:30 PM
- Leclerc Paridis (Nantes) close at 7:30 instead of 8:45.
- Super U Blain (Backwaterish city) close at 6:30 instead of 8.

The trend seem to be general, only the details varies.
Most, if not all store will display the specific closing time on their website.

For this year(2019) specifically, in Paris, the strike make it worst than other years.

Regarding the 1st of january : 
1st of may, 25th of december and 1st of january tends to be super bank holidays. 
Even stores that stays open most Sundays and other Banks holidays tend to be closed those days.
As a rule of thumb, consider that all stores are closed on 1st of January.